# Table - how to expand from specific column

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am expanding my table rows on click using expandedRowRender, and they both expand from first column. Is there a way to specify from which column the row should expand from?  For example, only expand from column 2 onwards?

```
columns = [
{
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
},
{
    title: "Surname",
    dataIndex: "surnamen",
},
{
    title: "Region",
    dataIndex: "region",
},];

<Table
    bordered
    dataSource={this.dataSource}
    columns={this.columns}
    expandRowByClick={true}
    expandIconAsCell={false}
    expandedRowRender={(expaned) => expaned ? <minitable /> : null}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `children` to the specific column:

```
        dataSource={[
          {
            name: 'Alex',
            surnamen: 'Abramov',
            region: 'React-Realm',
            children: [{ surnamen: 'myData' }]
          }
        ]}
```

After that, you can control the `indentSize` prop.

Check out the demo, try filling `indentSize={80}` in `InputNumber`.

[image: Edit ecstatic-cannon-4cj2b]